# Git checkout failing after pulling and changing .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull, git-checkout

Suppose I have in my local repo two branches 'master' and 'new', in master I decided to put a folder 'folder/' in .gitignore and the I pulled from the repo into master, adding a new folder 'temp/' Now when I want to checkout to 'new', I have this

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
.folder/subfolder/somefile
.folder/subfolder/somefile
tmp/somefiles(1),tmp/somefiles(2)...
```

(I commited before checking out out) I tried to run git rm --cached to the 'temp/'and 'folder/' folder and I don't understand why I get this message (and I think check out process is not really clear for me). Some one can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message basically means that the listed files are now untracked, but the branch you are checking out has them tracked. In result this would remove your local (untracked) version of those files, and replace them by whatever is stored in the branch you are checking out.

The reason for this is that you removed the folder from the repository but the files are still there; `git rm --cached` will only remove the files from the index, but not delete the files physically. So when you check out a different version, which still tracks those files, you get the conflict.

If you want to delete the files anyway, you can just remove them directly (`rm <file>`). Then after checking out the different branch, of course that one will still bring those files over, so you might want to remove them on that branch too (or later merge the removal into that branch).

Comment: +1  Also I would read up a bit on what checkout is.  Its different from other source control systems and, like quite a few of git's command, its name is misleading.  It's about switching branches not 'checking out' a single file per se.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Ok i am missing something about checkout : does the changes cleanly commited on master have an impact on the new checked out branch 'new' ?

Comment: @Newben No, what you commit on `master` does not automatically have any impact on `new`; they are independent pointers to commits in the history. A checkout in Git does not do anything about the history or branches; it is a command that only affects the working directory, and that is where your error occurs: You have files in your working directory that would be overwritten by a checkout, so Git warns you about this, so that you don’t accidentally lose those files.

Comment: @Newben As you untracked the files before (using `git rm --cached`, which does not affect the working directory either but just removes the files from the index), they are still physically in your working directory (untracked, ignored). So if you wanted to remove them completely, you could have just used `git rm`. But you can just manually remove them now as well for the same effect.